# How to insert an "index.php" into every url using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Example: My Site gets called like that:

```
www.mysite.com/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2
```

Now, .htaccess needs to rewrite this URL into:

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/controller/method/parameter1/parameter2
```

But the problem is: In case of an **img**, **css** or **js** directory, no redirection should happen.

How can I achieve this? What must I put to .htaccess? I just added this line but nothing happens:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|images)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but this should work:

```
RewriteRule !^((css|js|images)/.*)$ index.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L, NE]
```

`%{REQUEST_URI}` will be the original `/controller/method...` stuff, including the ?query part hopefully. `NE` prevents double escaping of stuff, and `L` means no further rules are applied.

Comment: what does !^((css|js|images)/.*)$ exactly do?

Comment: Just matches any url that doesn't (!) start (^) with css/ or js/ or images/

Comment: thanks! I guess I must turn on the mod-rewrite engine as well?

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting an Internal Server Error. RewriteEngine is on. However, this one worked with no error: RewriteRule index.html$ index.php   so my mod-rewrite is basically fine, I guess?